# For comprehensions in Elixir when n = 0

Tags: elixir

I want to use a for comprehension in Elixir for looping n times and accumulating some result for each time.

An example:

```
for i <- 0..n, y <- 1..3, do: y
```

This will loop 1 time when n is 0. I tried several other ways to get an empty list when n is 0, but can't see how to do it without using verbose constructs, which defeats the whole purpose of the comprehension. I realize this is because the range is inclusive. But I guess there must be a way to get exclusive ranges, or some other way to achieve empty for comprehensions while still being as readable. I just couldn't find it.

I want to know whether using a comprehension for this is reasonable in Elixir. If I have to make a long expression within the comprehension, or make my own helper functions, I'll just stick to other methods.

Comment: You want Elixir to generate an empty list when n is 0 in that comprehension you specified above?  Your question isn't super clear.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Yes, basically. I edited the question a bit. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0..n` is a inclusive range. Mathematically speaking you have `[0, n]` and you need `[0, n)`.

As I see it,there are at least two ways of approaching what you're intending to do.

The first one is to define a function that implements a exclusive range like:

```
defmodule Util do
  def range(from..to), do: range(from, to)

  def range(n, n), do: []
  def range(from, to) when to < 0, do: from..(to + 1) |> Enum.to_list()
  def range(from, to) when to >= 0, do: from..(to - 1) |> Enum.to_list()
end
```

This function always returns a list, never a range, just to keep consistency:

```
import Util
for _ <- range(0..n), y <- 1..3, do: y
```

Or

```
import Util
for _ <- range(0, n), y <- 1..3, do: y
```

The other solution is to avoid the comprehension at all:

```
1..3 |> List.duplicate(n) |> Enum.flat_map(&(&1))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I set this as an answer as it indicates comprehensions are pretty much useless in Elixir as a replacement for looping. That's very disappointing. I almost can't believe there is no exclusive range. I was really starting to enjoy the completeness of Elixir and how things fit together. This just feels wrong :( Well, well, whatcha gonna do? Thanks :)

Comment: @morten They are not useless. Remember that Elixir is a functional language, so it has it's own way of doing stuff. You can try to code imperative code in Elixir, but it will feel weird. List comprehension is useful to simulate backtracking, for example. So you could have the power of Prolog in Elixir, just by using comprehensions and a bit of knowledge about monads.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your comprehension doesn't return an empty list is because the range `0..0` is not empty.  This is apparent if you run `0..0 |> Enum.map(fn x -> x end)`; you'll get back `[0]`.  The `x..y` syntax is shorthand for "give me a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) of numbers starting with `x` and ending with `y`"; unsurprisingly, a list of all integers starting from zero and ending with zero contains a single number - zero - and therefore so should `0..0`.

In other words, `0..n` (when converted to a List) will always have a length of `n + 1`.  Thus, so will a comprehension over that list.

If you want to exclude the first item in an Enumerable, you can use `Enum.drop/2` for that.  Thus, to perform the second comprehension `n` times instead of `n + 1` times (which I think is your objective based on what you've written), the following ought to do the trick (assuming `n` is defined, of course):

```
for i <- (0..n |> Enum.drop(1)), y <- 1..3, do: y
```